# Issues installing/building the CGAL Library with vcpkg manager

Tags: c++, windows, cgal, vcpkg

To start, I am new to C++ and its package managers so there is a good chance that I just did something dumb.

Note: I am on a 64bit Windows 10 system, I have Clion and visual studio 2019 installed and want to start using CGAL's library. To do so, I simply followed the steps on their [website](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/windows.html) to install the things that I need:

```
mkdir vcpkgclone
cd vcpkgclone
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
vcpkg install yasm-tool:x86-windows
vcpkg install cgal:x64-windows
```

However, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_fail_port_install.cmake:97 (message):
  The yasm-tool port is only intended to be built for x86 Windows

  Architecture 'x64' not supported by yasm-tool!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ports/yasm-tool/portfile.cmake:1 (vcpkg_fail_port_install)
  scripts/ports.cmake:142 (include)


Error: Building package yasm-tool:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: yasm-tool:x64-windows
  Vcpkg version: 2021-01-13-d67989bce1043b98092ac45996a8230a059a2d7e

Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.
```

Your assistance in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yeah, that's broken at the moment, see bug reports on vcpkg's github. If you are ok with not using the latest versions, you can reset vcpkg to last year's version...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Awesome, can you send me a link to send me in the right direction, or maybe the next steps I should take to get the older version?

Comment: Er, it is git, so after the git clone, use `git log` to choose some random commit from a few months ago, `git checkout thehashofthecommit`, and continue with the same steps (you may not need the line with yasm). If it doesn't work, try some other commit...

Comment: Actually, they have some tags, so you could try `git checkout 2020.11-1` or `git checkout 2020.07` or some other tag.

Comment: So this is what I did to find an older commit: `git log --before 200.days.ago`, then selected the following vesion `git checkout a150b774a0d7b1bb7ede7e9f69be2340e54a7914`. Next, I simply ran `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` followed by `vcpkg install cgal:x64-windows`. [running now, will update if sucessful]

Comment: @MarcGlisse This seems to have given me a successful build, thanks for your help!